# Does Mountain Lion (10.8.4) come with SharePoint plug-ins, or did I just install these?

Tags: macos, ms-office, microsoft-sharepoint

I did a custom installation of Microsoft Office 2011 for Mac on my MacBook Air running 10.8.4., but I changed my mind and decided to uninstall it.

I only installed Word, Excel, and Proofing Tools (English only).

I'm reading up on how to fully remove all the tidbits Microsoft sprinkled about, and I noticed a couple files on my system:

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/SharePointBrowserPlugin.plugin
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/SharePointWebKitPlugin.webplugin
```

I didn't include SharePoint in the installation, so I'm not sure that's where these files came from. It's a new machine, so the only alternative is that they were included with OS X 10.8.4, in which case I'm inclined to leave them be.

Does anybody know more about these files, where they likely came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two files are not part of Apple's installed software on 10.8.4.

I would chalk it up to Microsoft's installer.

You can research this in depth with a tool like Pacifist by http://www.charlessoft.com